# Appearing and disappearing in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to create two new methods for jQuery that makes appear and disappear objects.
I dont want to use the jQuery methods `show()` and `hide()` (neither `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()`) because :

- the effect is not gradual
- when a `div` `hides`, then the object is not present anymore in the page and all the other `div` move.

My code does not work : objects disappear but don't appear.

Any clue ?

```
jQuery.fn.disappear = function() {
    this.fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
    this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
};
```

and

```
jQuery.fn.appear = function() {
     this.css('visibility', 'visible');
     this.fadeTo('slow', 1);
};
```

Comment: `fadeTo` is between 0 and 100, on the second function you have 1

Comment: and you have show() and hide() methods in jQuery...

Comment: @jackJoe not according to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) :"opacity - A number between 0 and 1 denoting the target opacity."

Comment: What if you don't change the `visibility` and rely on `opacity` to do the trick?

Comment: Are you calling the `appear` method correctly? Can you show us a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jywkW/ @JanDvorak

Comment: I call the method `appear` in `$(window).resize()`. http://jsfiddle.net/jywkW/2/

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'css'` in the callback to `fadeTo` so the `visibility` is never actually `hidden`

Comment: Very strange : because if I remove ` this.css('visibility', 'hidden');` the effect is different (for instance, you can still select the text)

Comment: It seems that the problem comes from the fact that I define methods (it is my first time). Without methods, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 'this' is used in a custom jQuery function, it's value is a jQuery object.  When 'this' is used inside a callback function it's a DOM object.

The correct code is:

```
jQuery.fn.disappear = function() {
    this.fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
    jQuery(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
};
```

and

```
jQuery.fn.appear = function() {
     this.css('visibility', 'visible');
     this.fadeTo('slow', 1);
};
```

Comment: That's just the way jQuery was created.  "this" always means "this" object.  When you had a method to jQuery's prototype, 'this' is referring to the jQuery object itself.  When you have a callback function, a reference to the DOM object is passed in.  Check out: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
jQuery.fn.disappear = function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
    });
};
jQuery.fn.appear = function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1, function(){
        console.log(this);
    });
};
```

You were missing a $() around your `this`. http://jsfiddle.net/jywkW/4/

The visibility rule is unnecessary, but you can keep it if you like.

Comment: The visibility is in case of you have text or links inside your div.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes it does. See my fiddle. You didn't fix it in yours.

Answer (score 1):

why so hard ?
Only use fadeOut and fadeIn
to disappear:

```
jQuery.fn.disappear = function(duration,callback) {
 this.animate({opacity:0},duration,callback);
};
```

and to appear:

```
jQuery.fn.appear = function(duration,callback) {
 this.animate({opacity:1},duration,callback);
};
```

and to access it, you can do it with:

```
$(function(){
  $.appear(1000,function(){
    // Write a callback
    // Like $(this).css('visibility','visible');
  });
  $.disappear(1000,function(){
    // Write a callback
    // Like $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
  });
});
```